# What is the Name of Mr. Universe's Moon?

Tags: firefly, serenity, joss-whedon

In the movie "Serenity", Mr. Universe lives on a small Moon enveloped by an ion cloud. It's where the final battle takes place. Does this moon have a name? I can't seem to find any information on that. If the moon does not have a name or the name is not known, maybe you can tell me the name of the planet which it orbits?

Thanks a bunch in advance for any info you can provide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The Verse in Numbers](http://pics.fireflyprops.net/TVIN-2.0.pdf), which was published to go with the semi-official [Complete and Official Map of the Verse](http://store.qmxonline.com/Complete-and-Official-Map-of-The-Verse_p_54.html) (larger image [here](http://i.picresize.com/images/2013/02/06/BMhCv.jpg)), has a listing on page 5.80 for the place Mr. Universe lived (at the bottom of the page it says "Population: Mr. Universe (deceased)"), it's just called "Station 2E". Although it's in the section for "Kalidasa", Sean Clancy pointed out in the comments that the "Kalidasa + 150" on its page probably just refers to its orbital position relative to Kalidasa, I think the idea is that it shares the same orbit around White Sun as Kalidasa does (White Sun being the central star in the Verse)--next to "Kalidasa + 150" it says "A/2260(White Sun)r25m9", and looking at other pages it seems like whatever is in the parentheses in that line for a given planet or moon's page, that's what it's supposed to be in orbit around (I also see that its orbital distance is given as 121 AU, same as Kalidasa's own "Verse Location" listed on p. 5.01). I don't think Station 2E was really a moon at all since it doesn't have a planet listing at the top of the page (compare with something like "Lennox" on 5.75, which is a moon of the planet "Salisbury"), just a "[Cortex](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Cortex) relay station", although it does say it was "terraformed" in 2305 so that must mean it's built on some natural body.

Page 7.04 has more on Cortex relay stations, it's mentioned that in the mid 2200s terraforming was creating waste in the form of "large clouds of ionized particles and terraforming nanobots that were collecting in a planet’s Van Allen belts", and that there was also a problem with communications traffic overwhelming the existing Cortex system, and that:

> These problems were seen as unrelated until one day when a Cortex
>   engineer started talking shop over lunch with a technician from DES. A
>   side project was created to see if there was some way the cloud could
>   be tuned so that it would pass transmissions. Instead, they discovered
>   that the ion cloud could act as a giant antenna. This solved the
>   problem faced by those charged with expanding Cortex coverage to keep
>   pace with outward expansion. A large asteroid or small moon could be
>   terraformed to create the Van Allen belts that the ion cloud needed as
>   a starting framework. With the cloud concentrations so high, the
>   asteroid chosen could be away from any star. A body could be selected
>   out in inter-cluster space. The cloud would amplify the weak solar
>   radiation that reached it, making the surface barely habitable for the
>   Cortex crews that would build the relay stations, antenna and server
>   farms.
>
> Four large asteroids of terrafomable size were chosen to be the first
>   of the new Cortex Relay Stations. They were located in the L4 and L5
>   Lagrangian points for Georgia and Red Sun.

So, I think Mr. Universe's Cortex station was most likely meant to have been built on an asteroid, at least according to the writers of The Verse in Numbers. In our own solar system there are some large asteroids that are spherical like planets or moons, such as [Ceres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceres_(dwarf_planet)) (due to be photographed up close by the [Dawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)) probe in February 2015). Station 2E's listed diameter is 992 km, very close to the real diameter of Ceres which is estimated as 950 km.

Comment: Actually, Cortex Relay Station 2E is in orbit around White Sun, not Kalidasa. The Kalidasa reference on that page is to its relative position in orbit, at 150 degrees from Kalidasa's position (Kalidasa orbits White Sun as well). This puts Mr. Universe's complex in relative proximity to the edges of the Blue Sun system, and therefore to Miranda and Reaver space.

Comment: @Sean Clancy - Thanks, I incorporated some of that information into the answer, but how do you know that 150 degrees from Kalidasa would be near the Blue Sun system? Is Blue Sun's own angular position relative to Kalidasa given somewhere?